# Return @Async method result in Spring MVC and return it to Ajax client - continuation

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

This is continuation of this question:

[Return @Async method result in Spring MVC and return it to Ajax client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907011/return-async-method-result-in-spring-mvc-and-return-it-to-ajax-client)

I have `@Async` task which calculates something and return it to the Future the calculation happens on the request and might take up to 15 minutes. I don't want to create new Ajax request every few seconds to check whether calculation is done and I don't want to keep my connection Open for up to 15 minutes till result is calculated.

What might be the best solution for Spring MVC in such cases?

Comment: I would expect a question like this:  I'm not sure If Spring MVC can work with Comet and if yes, how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you definitely don't want to keep the connection open.

With respect to eliminating polling requests, I'm not sure you have a choice.

Remember HTTP is a stateless request/response protocol.

You will need some sort of polling to check on the status.

Can you send out an email to the user containing a link to the calculation once it is done?

You can also take a look at the Comet framework.  Comet allows us to extend HTTP capabilities by keeping open a connection and allowing the server to push data to the client.